# FileInfo.MoveTo generating error in C#.Net script in SSIS package

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a C#.Net script that moves a file to a directory and adds an increment to the file name if the file already exists.  It works perfectly in one of my packages, but I copied it for another package and it fails with the following error message:

```
    DTS SCript Task has encounter an exception in user code:
    Project name: ST_<blablabla>
    Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target,Object[] arguments,Signature si, Boolean constructor)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] paramters, Object[] arguments)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
    at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingsFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine ExecuteScript()
```

Here's the actual code:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        string fileName = Dts.Variables["LoopFiles"].Value.ToString();

        System.IO.FileInfo file2 = new System.IO.FileInfo(Dts.Variables["FolderPath"].Value + fileName);

        int count = 1;
        string fullPath =Dts.Variables["FolderPath"].Value.ToString() +  Dts.Variables["LoopFiles"].Value.ToString();
        string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
        string newFullPath = fullPath;

        while (File.Exists(newFullPath))
        {
            string tempFileName = string.Format("{0}({1})", fileNameOnly, count++);
            newFullPath = Path.Combine(path, tempFileName + extension);
        }

        DialogResult button3 = MessageBox.Show(file2.ToString());

        file2.MoveTo(newFullPath);

        DialogResult button5 = MessageBox.Show("Last Step");

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

As a note, button3 pops up as it should in the routine at runtime, but the error comes up before button5 displays.  Any information as to why this is being difficult would help considerably.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have to see exception - rewrite code to catch it:

```
try{
    file2.MoveTo(newFullPath);
    DialogResult button5 = MessageBox.Show("Last Step");
}catch(Exception ex){
    DialogResult button6 = MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

and i think that it's bad idea to use MessageBoxes at all - it's much better to use console applications and write messages to StdOut

Comment: Ahhh, perfect!  Turns out I was using the wrong variable for the source path.  Thank you very much, and I plan on using your advice on MessageBoxes.